# how to prevent javascript function from changing other values in html form

Tags: javascript

I have two select blocks in my html form:

```
<select id="select1">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" onchange="someFunc()">
<option>A/option>
<option>B</option>
</select>
```

I have a validateForm() function called from the form tag @onSubmit. the "someFunc" function populates some innerHTML elsewhere in the form. The issue I'm having, is that when I hit submit, the value of select1 reverts to its original default value, and the validateForm function fails.

the someFunc function is really long, so I didn't post the whole thing, but essentially what it does is check a string value and populate html, like:

```
if(select2.value = 'A'){
     document.getElementById('anotherElement').innerHTML= '<h1>a new tag</h1>';
}
```

is there another att besides @onChange?

Ok, here is a complete html form that describes the problem I am having:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript q</title>
<script>
    function updateTag(){
document.getElementById('newHeading').innerHTML='<p     id="status">updated</p>';

    }


    function validateForm(){
        var s1 = document.getElementById('select1');
        var s2 = document.getElementById('select2');

        if( s1.value = 'please select' ){
                alert('please select a value from the pulldown');
                return false;
            }

        // updated html needs to have been performed and value selected
        if(document.getElementById('status') == null ){
                alert('status does not exist');
            }

    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Javascript Q</h1>

<form id="testForm" onSubmit="return validateForm();">

<select id="select1">
    <option>please select</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" onchange="updateTag()">
    <option>please select</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>       
<div id="newHeading">

</div>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

what happens is, I select a value from each pulldown, hit submit, then the value of select1 reverts to its orig val, and fails the validation

hope that's better.

thanks, 
bp

Comment: can you post up the someFunc() definition?

Comment: @EudisDuran: it's really long...wasn't sure how much to post. Please see edited q

Comment: @all: added more complete form, hope that question is better and more helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mea culpa, totally stupid oversight on my part

```
if( s1.value = 'please select' ){
```

should be

```
if( s1.value == 'please select' ){
```

sorry for stupid oversight

Answer (score 0):

I think what this does is it sends the info out (Actually submits it) making the feilds go blank again.
A tip would be to

```
return false
```

On your validateForm() if you just want to populate some div's and whatnot. If you actually want it to submit, then you'd probably want something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
     //Do your checks and innerHTML manipulation here before it sends the info away.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using return mentioned by Robin Jonsson you should use preventDefault() to prevent submitting the form when you hit submit.

Comment: no - thats not correct. return false does both preventDefault() AND stopPropagation()

Comment: No, it is correct. Using `return false;` in a jQuery event handler is the ONLY time both of those are executed. In normal Javascript event handlers, `return false;` is ONLY equivalent of `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: ok - so we should not start the discussion again - I think it's easier to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Exactly, the accepted answer explains exactly what I'm saying. Thanks for providing the link though